# Updating All OLEDB Connections in Excel 2007 via Macro

Tags: excel, connection

I don't profess to be any master of Excel, so when these things arrive I can generally write a best-effort macro to sort out any bulk updates, but this one has me stumped.

When we migrate our reports that connect to an OLEDB source and Cube they are coming across with the following two connection settings:

```
.RefreshOnFileOpen = True
.RefreshPeriod = 10
```

I need all of these in a workbook to be update to:

```
.RefreshOnFileOpen = False
.RefreshPeriod = 0
```

Recording a macro and changing one connection results in the following VB script:

```
Sub ChangeConn()
'
' ChangeConn Macro
'

'
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Connection").OLEDBConnection
        .CommandText = Array("Something")
        .CommandType = xlCmdCube
        .Connection = Array( _
        "OLEDB;Provider=MSOLAP.3;Persist Security Info=True;User ID="""";Initial Catalog=Something;Data Source=Something;Location=Something" _
        , _
        "Something;MDX Compatibility=1;Safety Options=2;MDX Missing Member Mode=Error" _
        )
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .SavePassword = False
        .SourceConnectionFile = ""
        .MaxDrillthroughRecords = 1000
        .ServerCredentialsMethod = xlCredentialsMethodIntegrated
        .AlwaysUseConnectionFile = False
        .RetrieveInOfficeUILang = False
        .ServerFillColor = False
        .ServerFontStyle = False
        .ServerNumberFormat = False
        .ServerTextColor = False
    End With
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Connection")
        .Name = "Connection"
        .Description = ""
    End With
End Sub
```

So I thought that the following Macro would work:

```
Sub FixConn()
 For Each OLEDBConnection In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
  .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
 Next OLEDBConnection
End Sub
```

But no... So I'm going to keep trying to figure this out, but if anyone here can help me that would be great.

[EDIT#1]  Thanks to Andrew I'm a step closer and I'm pursuing this link here.  Seems I was altering this object in the wrong place.  :)  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb213295(office.12).aspx

[SOLUTION]

```
Sub ReFixConn()
    For Each PivotCache In ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches
        With PivotCache
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
        End With
    Next PivotCache
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the With block:

```
Sub FixConn()
 For Each OLEDBConnection In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
  With OLEDBConnection
   .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
   .RefreshPeriod = 0
  End With
 Next OLEDBConnection
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks mate. That brings me one step closer. As I said this isn't something I'm that learnt in. Only problem now is that I'm getting an error of "Object doesn't support this property or method", which sounds to me like I'm trying to alter this setting in the wrong area..

Comment: Solved :) 

Sub ReFixConn()
    For Each PivotCache In ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches
        With PivotCache
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
        End With
    Next PivotCache
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

This should work as well:

```
Sub FixConn()
 Dim cn as Workbookconnection
 For Each cn In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
  cn.OLEDBConnection.RefreshOnFileOpen = False
  cn.OLEDBConnection.RefreshPeriod = 0
 next
End Sub
```